# How to show a HTTP stream from VLC Player in Wireshark?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, http, tcp, wireshark

I just set up a HTTP stream of a video between my Server and Client system using the VLC media player (using the command line). Both the systems run Ubuntu 20.04

```
vlc -vvv <path to video file> --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}standard:{access=http,mus=ts,dst=:8080/}'
```

Now I try to visualize the packets in Wireshark. Unfortunately, I can most only see TCP packets being sent between Server and Client but I cannot see any upper communication Layer (like HTTP). However, HTTP is activated to be shown in Wireshark (under Analyse -> Activate Protocols)

In the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEVY8.png) I only see a single HTTP frame and afterwards only TCP.

Does anyone have a solution for that? Or is that behaviour expected?

Best regards!

Comment: Well most of the "HTTP reponse" will be the video. Did you check the packets immediately following the HTTP request yet? They could contain the response headers.

Comment: @Daniel the screenshot I attached shows the communication immidiately after the communication has started. After this one HTTP message from the Client (192.168.0.3) to the Server, I can only see TCP messages in Wireshark. 
Shouldn't all the responses be packed in a HTTP message also?